# Why does the useQuery hook in react-query force me to check if the returned data is not undefined

Tags: typescript, react-query

I'm experimenting with react-query as a replacement for my custom logic when loading data from a server in a react application.

What I cannot seem to understand is why (at least) the TypeScript typing suggests that the `data` property the object returned by `useQuery` can be `undefined`?

If I remove the `if (!query.data) {return <span>No data found</span>;}` guard in the following example, TypeScript complains that `query.data` can be `undefined`.

When running the example it does not seem to be undefined but (at least) the TypeScript definition assumes that it might be.

Is there any documentation that I've missed explaining why `data` might be undefined?
Why does the typing suggest that `data` can be undefined?
Is there a situation where `data` can be undefined at runtime?
Could should not the API itself make this check and generate an error if data is really undefined?

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useQuery} from 'react-query';

type TodoType = {
    id: number,
    title: string,
};

const todos: TodoType[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'bar',
    },
];

const getTodos = (): Promise<TodoType[]> => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(todos), 250));

export const Todos = (): JSX.Element => {
    const query = useQuery('todos', getTodos);
  
    if (query.isLoading) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
    }
  
    if (query.isError) {
        const error = query.error instanceof Error ? query.error.message : 'Error';
        return <span>{error}</span>;
    }

    // why is this check needed?  
    if (!query.data) {
        return <span>No data found</span>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {query.data.map((todo) => (<li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is this check needed?

because the state machine internally has 4 main states:

- loading
- error
- success
- idle

types are narrowed depending on it, but in your example, you only eliminate loading and error from the union. What remains is success or idle. If you eliminate idle as well, only success remains and the check is unnecessary.

You might want to take a look at react-query v4 though. We have removed the `idle` state from the main state machine there, which would make the extra check in your example unnecessary.

### Update for react-query v5

As of react-query v5, the behavior has been changed again, and the state previously called 'loading' is now called 'pending', which means you need to check for the 'error' and 'pending' states before the data can be assumed to be available and also recognized as such by TypeScript.

In v5 there's still an 'isLoading' property, but this property represents something a bit different. For more information, see the relevant section on the [migration to v5 guide](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#status-loading-has-been-changed-to-status-pending-and-isloading-has-been-changed-to-ispending-and-isinitialloading-has-now-been-renamed-to-isloading).

Comment: Thank you. I did miss the `idle` state in the documentation but now I understand. In practice this should only happen when the `enabled` flag is `false`; correct? Would it therefore be save to always combine the `loading` and `idle` states?

Comment: yes, exactly. a query is only idle if its disabled and doesn't have any data yet, because if it has data, it will be success anyhow. In v4, we have a different approach: 3 primary states to give info about the data ((loading: no data, error: wrong data, success: good data) and a new secondary fetchStatus (idle, fetching, paused). All combinations of states are possible. see: https://react-query-beta.tanstack.com/guides/queries